# Change wp-login.php? Problem with .htaccess password protection and multi user shop

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, htaccess, password

I use a .htaccess password protection to secure my **wp-login.php**. For me as the admin of the WP/WooCommerce installation everything works fine so far (my password manager helps me to remember the tons of passwords). But now I have the problem, that there are are also registered customers which should be able to see their own customer accounts.

When these customers want to log out from their account, they click on the link **/customer-logout/** (which is in fact just the *wp-login.php*) and the .htaccess password protection appears. But, of course, my customers don´t have this password (and should not have).

Is there any solution for this? Maybe it´s possible to create a new logout function just for the user role "customer"? Or maybe you have any other ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: That's the point of password protection, so no one else can access it. You can use a plugin to create your custom login/logout pages, without even the need to access `wp-login.php`.

Comment: You could try the plugin [Theme My Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/). It has several hook/filters you can use to manipulate certain actions.

Answer (score 0):

check this may be useful i had similar issue  https://ivycat.com/protect-wordpress-login-brute-force-attacks-htaccess/

Comment: Please note that link only answers are not helpful if the link dies, add gist of the solution here instead of linking to somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe I´m wrong, but the page you link to just says "Protect your site with a .htaccess" without any solution of the multi user problem ;)